# Как создать список по макету?

Tags: python, list, математика

Допустим у меня есть списки: pum , root , number

```
pum = [9 , 15 ,  4]

root = [3 , 2]

number = [15]
```

И мне надо чтобы в итоге получился список all_numbers

```
all_numbers = [3 , 15 , 2]
```

Также хочу заметить что 15(или любое другое число) могут стоять в разных частях списка

Например:

```
pum = [15 , 9 , 4]

root = [3 , 2]

number = [15]
```

И в итоге:

```
all_numbers = [15 , 3 , 2]
```

Как должен работать алгоритм:

Вначале в список добавляются числа 3 и 2 ,после чего, если 15 было посередине списка Pum,то оно добавляется в середину списка all_numbers,если в начале, то в начало и т.д.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: по какому принципу составляется `all_numbers`?

Comment: Вначале в список добавляются числа 3 и 2 ,после чего, если 15 было посередине списка Pum,то оно добавляется в середину списка all_numbers,если в начале, то в начало и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не до конца понял саму суть задания, но судя по описанию это должно вам помочь

```
pum = [9, 4, 15]

root = [3, 2]

number = [15]

all_numbers = []

all_numbers += root
all_numbers.insert(pum.index(15), 15)
print(all_numbers)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблема в том, что на месте пятнадцати может быть любое другое число, и тогда ваш алгоритм не работает.

Comment: Если вопрос еще актуальный, то в список number  вместо 15 добавьте нужное число, а в all_numbers.insert (pum.index(15), 15) вместо чисел 15 можете вставить нужные вам числа, например (pum.index(number[0]), number[0]). Это если вам нужно вставить число конкретно из списка number

Answer (score 1):

```
n = number[0]
result = root.copy()

result.insert(pum.index(n), n)
```